# Android WindowManager.LayoutParams y offset

Tags: android, layoutparams

I want to draw something on full screen programmatically from top of the screen. However, there is always a y axis offset. It seems the height of status (title) bar.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    params.width = 200;
    params.height = 300;

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gd.setColor(Settings.highlightColor);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageDrawable(gd);
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.addView(iv, params);
```

I already set full screen in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Here is what I got:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` to your `LayoutParams`:

```
paramsFlags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
```

Comment: Tried, but with no luck.